# Импорт CSV файла в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

При импорте CSV файла в Pandas возникает проблема, так как разделителем в этом файле является `#`, но решётка также используется в первом столбце как часть текста, из-за этого она воспринимается как разделитель и появляется ошибка
[image]

Comment: 1.Ваш код.
2.Добавляйте код и ошибку текстом, скрин неудобно читать, невозможно копировать.

Comment: Добавьте пример содержимого файла с этими проблемами. Думаю, вам как-то придётся предобработать файл перед чтением в Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю предобработать ваш файл перед чтением в Pandas.
Примерно так сделать с каждой строчкой, считав построчно имеющийся файл и записав его в новый файл:

```
n_fields = 13
old_separator = '#'
new_separator = ';' # подставьте символ-разделитель, которого точно нет в вашем файле

for line in in_file:
    chunks = line.split(old_separator)
    new_line = old_separator.join(chunks[:-n]) + new_separator.join(chunks[-n:])
```